Raspberry Pi 4 with the QT5.15 program running, the resistive touch screen does not respond to pressing
I have Qt5.15 embedded with Linux Raspberry Pi 4. My touchscreen does not respond to pressing.
More details:
display ids-3210r-40sva1e.
ver. Linux pi 5.10.103-v7l+ #1529 SMP Tue Mar 8 12:24:00 GMT 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux

Qt Cross-compiling.
Log build:
      Mode ................................... release

  Optimize release build for size ........ no

  Building shared libraries .............. yes

  Using C standard ....................... C11

  Using C++ standard ..................... C++17

  Using ccache ........................... no

  Using new DTAGS ........................ yes

  Relocatable ............................ yes

  Using precompiled headers .............. yes

  Using LTCG ............................. no

  Target compiler supports:

    NEON ................................. yes

  Build parts ............................ libs

Qt modules and options:

  Qt Concurrent .......................... yes

  Qt D-Bus ............................... yes

  Qt D-Bus directly linked to libdbus .... yes

  Qt Gui ................................. yes

  Qt Network ............................. yes

  Qt Sql ................................. yes

  Qt Testlib ............................. yes

  Qt Widgets ............................. yes

  Qt Xml ................................. yes

Support enabled for:

  Using pkg-config ....................... yes

  udev ................................... yes

  Using system zlib ...................... yes

  Zstandard support ...................... no

Qt Core:

  DoubleConversion ....................... yes

    Using system DoubleConversion ........ yes

  GLib ................................... yes

  iconv .................................. no

  ICU .................................... yes

  Built-in copy of the MIME database ..... yes

  Tracing backend ........................ <none>

  Logging backends:

    journald ............................. no

    syslog ............................... no

    slog2 ................................ no

  PCRE2 .................................. yes

    Using system PCRE2 ................... yes

Qt Network:

  getifaddrs() ........................... yes

  IPv6 ifname ............................ yes

  libproxy ............................... no

  Linux AF_NETLINK ....................... yes

  OpenSSL ................................ yes

    Qt directly linked to OpenSSL ........ no

  OpenSSL 1.1 ............................ yes

  DTLS ................................... yes

  OCSP-stapling .......................... yes

  SCTP ................................... no

  Use system proxies ..................... yes

  GSSAPI ................................. no

Qt Gui:

  Accessibility .......................... yes

  FreeType ............................... yes

    Using system FreeType ................ yes

  HarfBuzz ............................... yes

    Using system HarfBuzz ................ yes

  Fontconfig ............................. yes

  Image formats:

    GIF .................................. yes

    ICO .................................. yes

    JPEG ................................. yes

      Using system libjpeg ............... yes

    PNG .................................. yes

      Using system libpng ................ yes

  Text formats:

    HtmlParser ........................... yes

    CssParser ............................ yes

    OdfWriter ............................ yes

    MarkdownReader ....................... yes

      Using system libmd4c ............... no

    MarkdownWriter ....................... yes

  EGL .................................... yes

  OpenVG ................................. no

  OpenGL:

    Desktop OpenGL ....................... no

    OpenGL ES 2.0 ........................ yes

    OpenGL ES 3.0 ........................ yes

    OpenGL ES 3.1 ........................ yes

    OpenGL ES 3.2 ........................ yes

  Vulkan ................................. yes

  Session Management ..................... yes

Features used by QPA backends:

  evdev .................................. yes

  libinput ............................... yes

  INTEGRITY HID .......................... no

  mtdev .................................. yes

  tslib .................................. yes

  xkbcommon .............................. yes

  X11 specific:

    XLib ................................. yes

    XCB Xlib ............................. yes

    EGL on X11 ........................... yes

    xkbcommon-x11 ........................ yes

QPA backends:

  DirectFB ............................... no

  EGLFS .................................. yes

  EGLFS details:

    EGLFS OpenWFD ........................ no

    EGLFS i.Mx6 .......................... no

    EGLFS i.Mx6 Wayland .................. no

    EGLFS RCAR ........................... no

    EGLFS EGLDevice ...................... yes

    EGLFS GBM ............................ yes

    EGLFS VSP2 ........................... no

    EGLFS Mali ........................... no

    EGLFS Raspberry Pi ................... no

    EGLFS X11 ............................ yes

  LinuxFB ................................ yes

  VNC .................................... yes

  XCB:

    Using system-provided xcb-xinput ..... no

    Native painting (experimental) ....... no

    GL integrations:

      GLX Plugin ......................... no

      EGL-X11 Plugin ..................... yes

Qt Sql:

  SQL item models ........................ yes

Qt Widgets:

  GTK+ ................................... no

  Styles ................................. Fusion Windows

Qt PrintSupport:

  CUPS ................................... yes

Qt Sql Drivers:

  DB2 (IBM) .............................. no

  InterBase .............................. no

  MySql .................................. no

  OCI (Oracle) ........................... no

  ODBC ................................... yes

  PostgreSQL ............................. yes

  SQLite2 ................................ yes

  SQLite ................................. yes

    Using system provided SQLite ......... no

  TDS (Sybase) ........................... yes

Qt Testlib:

  Tester for item models ................. yes

Serial Port:

  ntddmodm ............................... no

Qt SerialBus:

  Socket CAN ............................. yes

  Socket CAN FD .......................... yes

  SerialPort Support ..................... yes

Further Image Formats:

  JasPer ................................. no

  MNG .................................... yes

  TIFF ................................... yes

    Using system libtiff ................. yes

  WEBP ................................... yes

    Using system libwebp ................. yes

Qt QML:

  QML network support .................... yes

  QML debugging and profiling support .... yes

  QML just-in-time compiler .............. yes

  QML sequence object .................... yes

  QML XML http request ................... yes

  QML Locale ............................. yes

Qt QML Models:

  QML list model ......................... yes

  QML delegate model ..................... yes

Qt Quick:

  Direct3D 12 ............................ no

  AnimatedImage item ..................... yes

  Canvas item ............................ yes

  Support for Qt Quick Designer .......... yes

  Flipable item .......................... yes

  GridView item .......................... yes

  ListView item .......................... yes

  TableView item ......................... yes

  Path support ........................... yes

  PathView item .......................... yes

  Positioner items ....................... yes

  Repeater item .......................... yes

  ShaderEffect item ...................... yes

  Sprite item ............................ yes

QtQuick3D:

  Assimp ................................. yes

  System Assimp .......................... no

Qt Scxml:

  ECMAScript data model for QtScxml ...... yes

Qt Gamepad:

  SDL2 ................................... no

Qt 3D:

  Assimp ................................. yes

  System Assimp .......................... no

  Output Qt3D GL traces .................. no

  Use SSE2 instructions .................. no

  Use AVX2 instructions .................. no

  Aspects:

    Render aspect ........................ yes

    Input aspect ......................... yes

    Logic aspect ......................... yes

    Animation aspect ..................... yes

    Extras aspect ........................ yes

Qt 3D Renderers:

  OpenGL Renderer ........................ yes

  RHI Renderer ........................... no

Qt 3D GeometryLoaders:

  Autodesk FBX ........................... no

Qt Bluetooth:

  BlueZ .................................. yes

  BlueZ Low Energy ....................... yes

  Linux Crypto API ....................... yes

  Native Win32 Bluetooth ................. no

  WinRT Bluetooth API (desktop & UWP) .... no

  WinRT advanced bluetooth low energy API (desktop & UWP) . no

Qt Sensors:

  sensorfw ............................... no

Qt Quick Controls 2:

  Styles ................................. Default Fusion Imagine Material Universal

Qt Quick Templates 2:

  Hover support .......................... yes

  Multi-touch support .................... yes

Qt Positioning:

  Gypsy GPS Daemon ....................... no

  WinRT Geolocation API .................. no

Qt Location:

  Qt.labs.location experimental QML plugin . yes

  Geoservice plugins:

    OpenStreetMap ........................ yes

    HERE ................................. yes

    Esri ................................. yes

    Mapbox ............................... yes

    MapboxGL ............................. yes

    Itemsoverlay ......................... yes

QtXmlPatterns:

  XML schema support ..................... yes

Qt Multimedia:

  ALSA ................................... yes

  GStreamer 1.0 .......................... yes

  GStreamer 0.10 ......................... no

  Video for Linux ........................ yes

  OpenAL ................................. yes

  PulseAudio ............................. yes

  Resource Policy (libresourceqt5) ....... no

  Windows Audio Services ................. no

  DirectShow ............................. no

  Windows Media Foundation ............... no

Qt TextToSpeech:

  Flite .................................. no

  Flite with ALSA ........................ no

  Speech Dispatcher ...................... no

Qt Tools:

  Qt Assistant ........................... yes

  Qt Designer ............................ yes

  Qt Distance Field Generator ............ yes

  kmap2qmap .............................. yes

  Qt Linguist ............................ yes

  Mac Deployment Tool .................... no

  makeqpf ................................ yes

  pixeltool .............................. yes

  qdbus .................................. yes

  qev .................................... yes

  Qt Attributions Scanner ................ yes

  qtdiag ................................. yes

  qtpaths ................................ yes

  qtplugininfo ........................... yes

  Windows deployment tool ................ no

  WinRT Runner Tool ...................... no

Qt Tools:

  QDoc ................................... no

definition USB:
root@pi:~# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0eef:0001 D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd eGalax Touch Screen
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
root@pi:~#

Run evtest:
root@pi:~# evtest
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:    eGalax Inc. USB TouchController UNKNOWN
/dev/input/event1:    eGalax Inc. USB TouchController Stylus
/dev/input/event2:    eGalax Inc. USB TouchController`
check 1:
`root@pi:~# evtest
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:    eGalax Inc. USB TouchController UNKNOWN
/dev/input/event1:    eGalax Inc. USB TouchController Stylus
/dev/input/event2:    eGalax Inc. USB TouchController
Select the device event number [0-2]: 1
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0xeef product 0x1 version 0x210
Input device name: "eGalax Inc. USB TouchController Stylus"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 320 (BTN_TOOL_PEN)
    Event code 330 (BTN_TOUCH)
    Event code 331 (BTN_STYLUS)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value   2008
      Min        0
      Max     4095
    Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
      Value   2052
      Min        0
      Max     4095
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1716869875.859086, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value d0042
Event: time 1716869875.859086, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 1
Event: time 1716869875.859086, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 1488
Event: time 1716869875.859086, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 1990
Event: time 1716869875.859086, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1716869875.874988, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 1490
Event: time 1716869875.874988, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1716869875.878990, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 1496
Event: time 1716869875.878990, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1716869875.885024, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 1506
Event: time 1716869875.885024, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1716869875.890991, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 1518

The reaction to pressing the touchscreen.
Instal tslib:
apt-get install evtest libts-bin
apt-get install libts-dev
export TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/input/event1  
export TSLIB_FBDEVICE=/dev/fb0:

ts_calibrate and ts_test work.
next step:
export TSLIB_FBDEVICE=/dev/fb0
export TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/input/event1
export QT_QPA_EGLFS_NO_LIBINPUT=1
export QT_QPA_FB_TSLIB=1
export QT_QPA_GENERIC_PLUGINS=tslib:/dev/input/event1


I'm running the program in qt 5.15.
Qt displays the image on the display. The touchscreen does not respond to pressing. I tried to tap at different points on the screen. The touchscreen does not respond to pressing.
Help me!

what does not working mean? ... what exactly happens? ... no touch response? ... touch response at incorrect location? ... etc

yes  no touch response. The touch screen does not respond to pressing.

Although unspecified you appear to be running a 5 year old OS and have not specified connections.

usb touchscreen connection
